# How to find file accessed/created just few minutes ago

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, find

I always forget which file I edit one minutes ago, so I input `find . -cmin 1` or some other value but it worked exactly `1` minutes. I had to try `find . -ctime 2 /*or 3,4...*/`.

Then I find another approach which be better:

```
touch -t 12251134 empty /*similar format which 5 or 10 minutes ago */
find . -newer empty
```

I can use `date -d'-5minutes' +%m%d%H%M` caculate the time for me. I want to know if there is a simple way to find files accessed 1, 2 or 3... minutes ago.

Comment: Why not to use "history" ? So, using arrow keys, you can look up for previous commands you used.

Comment: I use `ls -Ahl -crt | tail -5`. So often that I made an alias for it. `mc` with modified-sorting would be even better.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Simply specify whether you want the time to be greater, smaller, or equal to the time you want, using, respectively:

```
find . -cmin +<time>
find . -cmin -<time>
find . -cmin  <time>
```

In your case, for example, the files with last edition in a maximum of 5 minutes, are given by:

```
find . -cmin -5
```

Comment: I wonder why they didn't include this helpful usage in the man page

Comment: Yes, it is there, right in **find man page**, just look for: *Numeric arguments can be specified as: +n, for greater than n; -n, for less than n; n, for exactly n.* Them kids who wrote these unix programs did wonders (:

Comment: Eh, kiiiinda. That bit about how you can use `+` and `-` is, at least on my system, one level up in the hierarchy: under the "Primaries" heading. I was surprised that it was only matching exactly so I checked for another.. well "primary" that would help. Eventually good ol' SO came to the rescue :)

Comment: Just a note that if you want mtime, there's also the mmin option

Answer (score 19):

If you have GNU find you can also say

```
find . -newermt '1 minute ago'
```

The `t` options makes the reference "file" for `newer` become a reference date string of the sort that you could pass to GNU `date -d`, which understands complex date specifications like the one given above.

Comment: For this simple case `-mmin` would work, but you can also say `-newermt 'yesterday'` or `-newermt '+ 2 weeks'` or even `-newermt '2PM last Sunday'`. Calculating these things by hand could be done, but it's much easier to let `find` figure it out.

Answer (score 12):

To find files accessed 1, 2, or 3 minutes ago use `-3`

```
find . -cmin -3
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know the file is in your current directory, I would use:

```
ls -lt | head
```

This lists your most recently modified files and directories in order.  In fact, I use it so much I have it aliased to 'lh'.

Comment: what if there are more than 10 files but you don't know the number. Then head doen't work

Comment: `head` still works for that purpose, 10 lines is just the default. You can specify however many you want. First five lines? `head -5`. First twenty lines? `head -20`. Same with `tail`